# Earth Engine Python Export task "Image.mask: Parameter 'image' is required"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am looking to export images to a Cloud Storage bucket to use as a training set for an Image Segmentation AI pipeline, and am using the following code to export out a the Image output from the EE Classifier

```
    igbpPalette = ['aec3d4', 
                   '152106', '225129', '369b47', '30eb5b', '387242',
                   '6a2325', 'c3aa69', 'b76031', 'd9903d', '91af40',
                   '111149', 
                   'cdb33b',
                   'cc0013',
                   '33280d',
                   'd7cdcc',
                   'f7e084',
                   '6f6f6f'
    ]
                            
    visParams = {'palette': igbpPalette, 'min': 0, 'max': 17, 'bands': ['B3', 'B2', 'B1']}
    banded_image = classified.visualize(visParams)
    task_config = {'banded_image': banded_image,
                    'description': f'{str(year)}-{month_string}-{day_string}',
                    'scale':30,
                    'maxPixels': 1e13,
                    'bucket':"training_images"}
    task=ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(**task_config)
    task.start()
```

The tasks are submitted to the Earth Engine console, but all fail with the error

> "Image.mask: Parameter 'image' is required".

I have tried with multiple Image objects in the task creation (non-visualised, pre-classification, etc), but all have the same result.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: what happens if you change the parameter name `banded_image` to `image` in your `task_config` dictionary? There is also a single quote missing from before `description`

Comment: The missing quote was a typo in the formatting. I have updated banded_image to image, but the same error occurs. I can only assume that the Image Collection filtering is too restrictive

Comment: It looks like the problem arises in your `mask` function, before this code for exporting.

Comment: The mask is from the Cloud Cover sample code `cloudScore = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(landsat).select('cloud') input = landsat.updateMask(landsat.mask().reduce('min'))
input= input.updateMask((cloudScore.lte(50)))` The image being masked is the first non-cloudy image from a ImageCollection filtered between 01-01-2000 and 31-12-2000